Redirect to the original web page after external idp authorization via Keycloak

An unauthorized user requests a resource through the frontend.
The user is redirected to the login page in keycloak, where the external idp was predefined.
The user clicks the idp’s button and is redirected to the login form via SSO.
The user successfully logs in and is redirected to the page https://keycloak/realms/realm/account/.

The question is:
Where can I set up a redirect to the front-end page from which the user originally came?
I only see Redirect URI like https://keycloak/realms/realm/broker/idp/endpoint in the ipd settings and I can’t change it.
Or what should the link look like where you need to go from the frontend to the keycloak in order to log in with an external idp, receive a keycloak token and return to the page from which you came?

It's not your problem. The RP does the "The user is redirected to the login page in keycloak", and Keycloak redirects back to the RP, not to you. You set the URI in Keycloak to whatver the RP tells you to set it.

@EML thanks for the answer.

what does the term RP mean?
"..and Keycloak redirects back to the RP, not to you." what do you mean by "me"? Frontend or something else? I'm actually a backender who is trying to set up a connection with keylock. I need to figure out how to set up a keycloak so that the frontend comes and leaves with a token. Maybe I should make some kind of router on the backend, or will setting up a keylock be enough? In this case, where should I set the redirect uri to frontend?


RP: "Relying Party, an application or website that outsources its user authentication function to an IDP." Lots of hits on the web; check the OAuth2 RFCs. Something like Apache/httpd. Unless you're actually writing an RP (very unlikely) you don't need to worry about this. You need to supply a lot more detail: in many cases, the frontend doesn't need to return a token to the client; the RP can just return a session cookie, for example.

@EML
Thanks for clarifying. The point is that we decided to abandon sessions in favor of tokens due to the requirements of some services.
At the moment I want to test receiving a token after authorization through the keycloak account console -> going to the external idp form and login -> redirecting to the web page I want. But after sso login I am redirected back to the account console

You need to draw a picture and ask another question. Show the client, the server, the app on the server with the protected resource that the client needs to talk to, and where you think Keycloak fits into this picture. You appear to be saying that the client needs the access token. If this is the case, the client needs to get the token directly from Keycloak, without involving the server. However, the server will still need to talk to Keycloak, for token introspection.

@pickstar, were you able to figure out how to redirect to the intended web page instead of the account console? (session or token)

When the frontend gets the token from Keycloak's token endpoint it should specify the redirect_uri parameter to be the one you want. Note that this needs to be configured in Keycloak's client configuration for Valid redirect URIs.
You should be aware of the security implications of a browser based application getting tokens directly as it is difficult for a browser based application to securely keep the tokens. This and other details can be found in OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps. Typically a Backend For Frontend or Token-Mediating Backend is more secure.
Authorization code flow consists of 2 parts, the authorization request where you get the code, and the token request where you exchange the code for the tokens. You can read more in The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework.
You can see the endpoints at https://{keycloak_uri}/realms/{realm}/.well-known/openid-configuration
authorization_endpoint: https://{keycloak_uri}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
token_endpoint: https://{keycloak_uri}/realms/{realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token
You should typically be using a library to make these requests as then you have some assurance that it will be implemented properly, for instance you need to send and verify the state parameter to prevent CSRF and the nonce parameter to prevent id token replay. You will also want to use PKCE.

Thanks for the answer! I am using the link: https://<keycloak_uri>/realms//protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=&redirect_uri=<web_page_uri>&response_type=code&scope=openid
but when I am redirected to the frontend page, I only see the session in cookies. Can you send an example of what the link should look like to get the keycloak token?

That's only the first part of authorization code flow. It should return the code for you to exchange for the tokens at the token endpoint. That said you should typically be using a library for this, you should also be sending a checking things like the state and nonce and use PKCE. I will edit the answer.
